# Default canvas dimensions

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Can anybody tell me why the default canvas size is 300 x 150 pixels?:

http://jsfiddle.net/VqNAV/

And why my 50 x 50 square ( http://jsfiddle.net/VqNAV/1/ ) get stretched when I change the canvas size: http://jsfiddle.net/VqNAV/2/

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I found an answer here: https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=13818#comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For canvas, if you do NOT want the context to be stretched, you must modify the HTML attributes. http://jsfiddle.net/VqNAV/3/

EDIT: I think the better question is why is it inline? There is nothing in the [HTML 5 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element) that specifies that this is how it should be. This was a decision upon the browser creators. The canvas acts as an image and is thus treated like an image which is also inline and also has a width and height.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem but didn't answered my first question :) Why is 300x150 the default? Shouldn't it be 100% width like block elements?

Comment: @revaxarts It's not a block element.

Comment: well, my question is answered now :)